# Gradle: com.android.support:support-v4:xx.x.x not supported in anymore in favor of AndroidX

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, implementation, androidx

I have an older project. However, a lot of functionality doesn't work anymore. However I want to use it, without changing much. How can I still use the old library?

[image: in activity]

[image: in build.gradle]

Comment: It is time to migrate to androidx. You can still use the old support libraries but pay attention to other dependencies like firebase or google play services that require androidx migration.

Comment: Ok, but is there a workaround in build.gradle to still use support-v4 implementations?

Comment: Just leave the support libraries dependencies. It is only a warning.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple
Select 4.x SDK building tools it will use old library and old gradle
And select target Android 28 from structures to publish it on playstore
**Note: You must install 4.x SDK before do that or will show you error